# Es normal que los valores varbinary y binary se almacenen así?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Las columnas varbinary y binary se almacenan en phpmyadmin como si fueran enlaces. Antes aparecian sin el modo enlace, y creo que el login no funciona por el hecho de que se almacena de esta forma tan peculiar. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero la forma de visualizacion no tiene nada que ver con el dato en si... como lo muestre phpmyadmin no deberia importar... si tenes problemas, viene por otro lado...